# Docked Control doesn't always have same width as parent

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

I have a panel docked to the top of another panel.  The parent panel lives inside of an Actipro DockManager.  If I resize the parent panel, everything is fine.  If I resize the form, the child panel doesn't end up with the same width as the parent panel.  Any idea how to fix this?  I tried manually setting the Width on the child panel and that is ignored.